# Replace all the keys in nested dictionary and merge duplicate keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that represents parent-child relationships. For example:

```
{
    "45273425f5abc05b->s": 
        {
            "12864f455e7c86bb->s": {
                "12864f455e7c86bbexternal_call->c": {}
            }
        },
    "c69aead72fcd6ec1->d": 
        {
            "8ade76728bdddf27->d": {
                "8ade76728bdddf27external_call->i": {}
            },
            "b29f07de47c5841f->d": {
                "107bec1baede1bff->l": {
                    "e14ebabea4785c3f->l": {
                        "e14ebabea4785c3fexternal_call->r": {}
                    },
                    "e36b35daa794bd50->l": {
                        "e36b35daa794bd50external_call->a": {}
                    }
                },
                "b29f07de47c5841fexternal_call->l": {}
            },
            "1906ef2c2897ac01->d": {
                "1906ef2c2897ac01external_call->e": {}
            }
        }
}
```

I want to do two things with this dictionary. Firstly I want to remove  everything before and including "->" i.e I want to update the keys. Secondly, after renaming there will be duplicate values in the nested dictionary. for example the second element in the dictionary. If there are two keys with the same name I want to merge them into one. So, the result will look like the following:

```
{
"s": 
    {
        "s": {
            "c"
        }
    },
"d": 
    {
        "d": {
            "i",
            "l": {
                "l": {
                    "r",
                    "a"
                }
            },
            "e"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? I have written this code so far.

```
    def alter_dict(nested_dict):
        new_dict = {}
        for k, v in nested_dict.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                v = alter_dict(v)
            new_key = k.split("->")[1]
            new_dict[new_key] = v
        return new_dict
```

It works for a simple one like the first element but doesn't work for the second one. It loses some information. The purpose of this is to create a graph with the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
def merge(d):
  r = defaultdict(list)
  for i in d:
    for a, b in i.items():
      r[a.split('->')[-1]].append(b)
  return {a:merge(b) for a, b in r.items()}

data = {'45273425f5abc05b->s': {'12864f455e7c86bb->s': {'12864f455e7c86bbexternal_call->c': {}}}, 'c69aead72fcd6ec1->d': {'8ade76728bdddf27->d': {'8ade76728bdddf27external_call->i': {}}, 'b29f07de47c5841f->d': {'107bec1baede1bff->l': {'e14ebabea4785c3f->l': {'e14ebabea4785c3fexternal_call->r': {}}, 'e36b35daa794bd50->l': {'e36b35daa794bd50external_call->a': {}}}, 'b29f07de47c5841fexternal_call->l': {}}, '1906ef2c2897ac01->d': {'1906ef2c2897ac01external_call->e': {}}}}
print(json.dumps(merge([data]), indent=4))
```

Output:

```py
{
    "s": {
        "s": {
            "c": {}
        }
    },
    "d": {
        "d": {
            "i": {},
            "l": {
                "l": {
                    "r": {},
                    "a": {}
                }
            },
            "e": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just want to know what if I don't want to merge them and keep them as is and only rename the keys?